# nspredicate for searching entity relationships

Tags: ios, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I wrote the following predicate for the following structure, not sure if its working correctly:

I have a Car.h managedobject

Car.h - name,
        make,
        model.

toCarParts relationship - CarPart.h - wheel,
                                              tire,
                                              mirror,
                                              etc...

i have an array with many Car.h objects
I want to find only those that have a tire  (so i have to look through toCarParts at all objects, and if any of the CarParts match my query, I need to pull that car into a results array)

will this predicate do this?

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY toCarParts.name == [c] %@", carPartString];
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work for you.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY toCarParts.name like %@", carPartString];
```